# Intersect unknown number of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-intersect

I'm trying to intersect an arbitrary number of PHP arrays, the count of which depends on a user provided parameter, each of which can have any number of elements.

For example:
array1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
array2(2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 23)
array3(a, b, 3, c, f)
...
arrayN(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 ... xn)

Since array_intersect takes a list of params, I can't build one array of arrays to intersect and have to work my way around this. I tried this solution: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/13004-array_intersect-unknown-number-arrays but this did not work, as an error is reported that array_intersect requires 2 or more params.

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this in a manner as simple as possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Create a new empty array, add each of your arrays to that, then use [call_user_func_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
$wrkArray = array( $userArray1,
                   $userArray2,
                   $userArray3
                 );
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$wrkArray);
```

Comment: Already tried that, as mentioned in the link in my original question. This is the error I get: "Warning:  array_intersect() [<a href='function.array-intersect'>function.array-intersect</a>]: at least 2 parameters are required, 1 given in..."

Comment: Silly me, I missed the "_array" part of call_user_func! Thank you!

Comment: @swader - it's an easy mistake to make... don't kick yourself too much over it :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$arrays = [
    $userArray1,
    $userArray2,
    $userArray3
];
$result = array_intersect(...$arrays);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use eval()!

Try this

```
$isect = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $N; $i++) {
    $isect = array_intersect($isect, ${'array'.$i});
}
```

or that

```
$arrays = array()
for ($i = 1; $i <= $N; $i++) {
    $arrays[] = ${'array'.$i};
}
$isect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arrays);
```

Comment: Please use **${'array' . $i}** if you really go this way.

Comment: The first option doesn't work, because the result is initialized to an empty array, the result of the following intersects will always be an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my answer very very late, but just want to share a small piece of code that helps me ,in case somebody needs it for this question.

```
print_r(array_intersect(array_merge($array1,$array2,...),$intersectionArr);
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use the splat operator (`...`) as in: `array_intersect(...$arrayOfArrays)` or interchangeably `call_user_func_array`.

It's in the code in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMlvtgT3t4E